# Regex match of a string with numbers and uppercase letters failing

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match `lasko17A565` in the list below but the regex fails?specifically I am trying to look for the string present in variable `train` in the front followed by any combination of numbers and uppercase letters, can anyone provide guidance why it fails?

```
import re
xbsfindupdates_output_list  = ['project-707.1.5 was found in the following updates of lasko:', '\tlasko17A565', '\tNewestlasko', '\tBuiltlasko']
train = 'lasko'
found_new_SDK = False
for SDK in xbsfindupdates_output_list:
    if re.match(r'%s[0-9A-Z]'%train,SDK):
        found_new_SDK = True
print found_new_SDK
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
False
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
True
```

Comment: Are there rules behind why `lasko17A565` is a match, or, if you're just looking for this exact match, then why not use string contains?

Comment: there are rules, `lasko17A565` is just one example,I need to able to look for the string present in variable `train` in the front followed by any combination of numbers and uppercase letters

Comment: So, in this example, does a match have to _begin_ with `lasko`?  Or, can `lasko` appear anywhere in a given match?

Comment: `lasko` is the train name,so train name has to be at the beginning

Comment: To begin with, you are iterating over a list of values, but you will only ever print out whether your regex matched the very last value in your list. Is that the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the error is in how you are building the regex pattern to be used here.  I suggest concatenating the input list together by space to form a single input string, and then using the following regex pattern with `re.findall`:

```
\b(lasko[A-Z0-9]+)\b
```

The word boundaries are appropriate here, because the `train` value should be bounded on the left by a tab, and on the right by a space.

```
xbsfindupdates_output_list  = ['project-707.1.5 was found in the following updates of lasko:', '\tlasko17A565', '\tNewestlasko', '\tBuiltlasko']
train = 'lasko'
inp = ' '.join(xbsfindupdates_output_list)
pattern = r'\b(' + train + r'[A-Z0-9]+)\b'
matches = re.findall(pattern, inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['lasko17A565']
```

**Edit:**

If you just want to find out if there is a match, then try:

```
xbsfindupdates_output_list  = ['project-707.1.5 was found in the following updates of lasko:', '\tlasko17A565', '\tNewestlasko', '\tBuiltlasko']
train = 'lasko'
inp = ' '.join(xbsfindupdates_output_list)
pattern = r'\b' + train + r'[A-Z0-9]+\b'
if re.search(pattern, inp):
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

Comment: is there a way to use `re.match`,I just need to know if there is a match or not ,don't the matched values

Comment: @user3508811 I gave you an option with `re.search`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for SDK in xbsfindupdates_output_list:
print(SDK,re.search("%s[0-9A-Z]+"%train,SDK))
if re.match("%s[0-9A-Z]+"%train,SDK.strip()):
    print("FOUND")
    found_new_SDK = True
print (found_new_SDK)
```

re.match is returning True iff both strings are same. Try re.search, which would search in string the required pattern

Answer (score 1):

Match objects are always true, and None is returned if there is no match. Just test for trueness. So instead of match, i used re.search here:

```
xbsfindupdates_output_list  = ['project-707.1.5 was found in the following updates of lasko:', '\tlasko17A565', '\tNewestlasko', '\tBuiltlasko']
    train = 'lasko'
    found_new_SDK = False
    for SDK in xbsfindupdates_output_list:
          if re.search(r'\b' + train + r'[\d\S]+', SDK):
               found_new_SDK = True
    print found_new_SDK
```

O/p:
True